# Rails ActionMailer previews not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, railstutorial.org, cloud9-ide

I have a mailer set up within the Rails Tutorial application which works fine.

The previews of the emails was working too when visiting the default path within c9.io: `https://app-name.c9users.io/rails/mailers/user_mailer`

Previously, this gave me the option to select which outbound email and which format, html or txt, I wanted to view a preview of.

Now, I get a response, as shown, on the page:

[image: unknown action]

And in the logs, I have a 404 with a mention about IP addresses which I don't understand:

```
Started GET "/rails/mailers/user_mailer" for 88.210.160.9 at 2017-11-15 16:43:20 +0000
Cannot render console from 88.210.160.9! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Rails::MailersController#preview as HTML
  Parameters: {"path"=>"user_mailer"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 252ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The log implies I can't access the preview unless I'm local to the server, although this was working fine previously. If I try to access a specific mailer method, I get the same error on the page:

[image: mailer 2]

And similar in the trace:

```
Started GET "/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation" for 88.210.160.9 at 2017-11-15 16:57:41 +0000
Cannot render console from 88.210.160.9! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Rails::MailersController#preview as HTML
  Parameters: {"path"=>"user_mailer/account_activation"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have views associated with the html & text versions of the emails and a working mailer - this all works as expect, but the previews won't display:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Password reset"
  end

end
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your mailer files bear a .html between their name and their .erb or .slim extension. I had the same issue.

Comment: My mailer's view files have either the extension `.html.erb` or, for the non-html ones, `.text.erb`.

Comment: Could you please name your views with relative path also?

Comment: I mean, do you have an `account_activation.html.erb` file for instance?